Installed Python 3.12.8. Getting "version conflict for package "Tk": have 8.6.15, need exactly 8.6.13"
I once had both Python 3.12 and 3.13 installed, but have since removed 3.13. I run the following simple program:
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome to LikeGeeks app")
window.mainloop()

When I try to run it, I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Temp\pythongui.py", line 2, in 
window = Tk()
^^^^
File "C:\Users\gsem6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 2346, in init
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories:
{C:\ActiveTcl\lib\tk8.6} C:/Users/gsem6/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/lib/tcl8.6/tk8.6 C:/Users/gsem6/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/lib/tk8.6 C:/Users/gsem6/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/lib/tk8.6 C:/Users/gsem6/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/lib/tk8.6 C:/Users/gsem6/AppData/Local/Programs/lib/tk8.6 C:/Users/gsem6/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/library
C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tk8.6/tk.tcl: version conflict for package "Tk": have 8.6.15, need exactly 8.6.13
version conflict for package "Tk": have 8.6.15, need exactly 8.6.13
while executing
"package require -exact Tk  8.6.13"
(file "C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tk8.6/tk.tcl" line 14)
invoked from within
"source -encoding utf-8 C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tk8.6/tk.tcl"
("uplevel" body line 1)
invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source -encoding utf-8 $file]"

This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.
I am an experienced programmer in several languages, but I am new to Python.
I started to remove Python 3.12 to get only one version of Python on my system but cancelled the removal while it was still running (Because I have vision problems and color blindness, I find the Python 3.13 colorized shell unusable and can't find a way to shut the colors off. The 3.12 shell was black on white text).
I removed 3.13 and tried the program again, but had the same result.
I decided to start with a clean slate and removed both 3.12 and 3.13.
I tried to install 3.12 again and it failed with an error "installation cancelled by user". After much googling and attempts, I got 3.12 installed by running the installation as administrator and the installation proceeded to completion, but the error still occurs.
